# Why can't my system can't find 'npm' (Node Package Manager)

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, path, node.js

I'm trying to use npm (Node Package Manager) on my OSX Snow Leopard. npm is installed in /usr/local/bin/  It's in $PATH (set in .bashrc) but when I'm logged in as a general user it can't be found, even with 'which npm'. But when I switch to an admin account it can be found, but the $PATH is the same in both accounts. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a silly question, but have you `source`ed your .bashrc? It's a common thing that I often forget to do.